# Linear edo system of variable coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $A(t) = \left[\begin{array}{l}2t&0&1\\0&2t&1\\0&-1&2t\end{array}\right]$ be the matrix of $\dot x = A(t) x $. The question is to obtain the resolvent matrix.

I did: $\dot x - \dot y = 2t(x-y) \implies x - y=0 // x-y=e^{t^2 }$ ... but when i substitute this on the third ecuation i don't know where to follow.  Any hint is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It'easier to compute the exponential matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Try computing solving first the system:
$$y'=2ty+z\\
z'=-y+2tz$$
computing the exponential matrix. Then plug the values in the equation $x'=2tx+z$, and solve it by Laplace's transformation.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \dot X = \left[\begin{array}{l}2t&0&1\\0&2t&1\\0&-1&2t\end{array}\right]X $$
Rewrite the system as:
$$ \dot X =2tI_3X+ \left[\begin{array}{l}0&0&1\\0&0&1\\0&-1&0\end{array}\right]X $$
Multiply by $e^{-t^2}$:
$$ \dot Xe^{-t^2} -2te^{-t^2}X=\left[\begin{array}{l}0&0&1\\0&0&1\\0&-1&0\end{array}\right]Xe^{-t^2} $$
$$\dot {(Xe^{-t^2}) }= \left[\begin{array}{l}0&0&1\\0&0&1\\0&-1&0\end{array}\right](Xe^{-t^2}) $$
Substitute $Z=Xe^{-t^2}$ in the system:
$$\dot {Z }= \left[\begin{array}{l}0&0&1\\0&0&1\\0&-1&0\end{array}\right]Z $$
The matrix has now constant coefficients.